# Finding the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{x^{4n}}{4n+3}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{x^{4n}}{4n+3}$$

Now we're given a hint to turn this into $x^{-3}\int g(t)dt$

I've gone ahead and done the following:

$$x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^n \frac{x^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$

And this turns into:

$$x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n+2}}\right)$$

Now we know for a power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^n q^{n}= \frac{1}{1-q}$$

And I need to turn the term from two lines ago into this form.

$t^{4n+2}=t^{4n}{t^2}=\left((t^4)^{n}*t^2\right)$

Now is my thought process correct here?

$$x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n+2}}\right)=x^{-3}t^2\sum_{n=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n}}\right)=x^{-3}\int\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t^4}\right)$$

(And of course after this comes the fraction decomposition and the integral.)

Comment: I think you meant to write the sums from $i=0$ to $n$.

Comment: Yes from n=0 to $\infty$, mistake on my part.

Comment: There is a conceptual error when the dummy variable $t^2$ was pulled outside the integral in the middle expression of the last line in the OP.  It was inserted tacitly back under the integral (another conceptual error) in the last line of the OP to arrive at a correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fine so far,
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n+3}}{4n+3} = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t^2}{1-t^4}\,dt = \frac{\text{arctanh}(x)-\arctan(x)}{2}$$
leads to:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n}}{4n+3} = \frac{\text{arctanh}(x)-\arctan(x)}{2x^3}$$
for any $x\in(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP

> Now is my thought process correct here?$$x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n+2}}\right)=x^{-3}t^2\sum_{n=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n}}\right)=x^{-3}\int\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t^4}\right)
> $$

Not quite.  There is a conceptual error when the dummy variable was pulled outside the integral in the middle expression. It was inserted tacitly back under the integral (another conceptual error) to arrive at a correct result.

To proceed correctly, we write

$$\begin{align}
x^{-3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x t^{4n+2}\,dt&=x^{-3}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^N t^{4n+2}\,dt\\\\
&=x^{-3}\lim_{N\to \infty}\int_0^x t^2\frac{1-t^{4N+4}}{1-t^4}\,dt\\\\
&=x^{-3}\int_0^x \frac{t^2}{1-t^4}\,dt
\end{align}$$

where the interchange of the limit with the integral is justified since the integrand converges uniformly on $x\in [-r,r]$ for all $0<r<1$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{-3}\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\int_0^x{t^{4n+2}} dt\right)=x^{-3} \left(\int_0^x t^2 \sum_{i=0}^n{t^{4n}} dt\right) = x^{-3} \left(\int_0^x t^2 \frac{1-t^{4n+4}}{1-t^4} dt\right) = x^{-3} \left(\int_0^x t^2 \frac{1}{1-t^4} dt\right)-x^{-3} \left(\int_0^x t^{4n+6} \frac{1}{1-t^4} dt\right).$$

The first integral is $$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|x+1\right|\right)-2\arctan\left(x\right)-\ln\left(\left|x-1\right|\right)}{4},$$ which is obtained by partial fractions and the second is also solved by partial fractions of $1+t^2$, $1-t$, and $1+t$ to get

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|x+1\right|\right)}{4}- \dfrac{\arctan\left(x\right)}{2}-\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac{x^{4i+3}}{4i+3}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|x-1\right|\right)}{4}.$$

Thus, we will not get much for finite $n$ since subtracting leads to original problem. However, for $n$ infinite, we do get the first term as answer. I do not see that we can solve for finite $n$ using this approach.